# A severe memory leak with Socket.io 1.2.1 (and earlier)

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, socket.io

I have a very simple socket.io server setup. My needs are to be able to communicate between server and client over sockets, but always on a one-to-one mode.
As such I created something simple as this on the client:

```
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('connect',function(){
        socket.emit('connected', UserName);
    });
```

And than on the server:

```
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('connected', function (userName) {
       if (userName !== null) {
         socket.join("RoomFor:"+ userName);
        }
    });
  });
```

So, each user has his own room I can now communicate with, and I can do this using my applicative userName (not socket id).

Now, on the same socket IO server, I also have express listening, with something like this:

```
app.get('/notify', function(req, res) {
  var data = querystring.parse(req.url.split('?')[1]);
  var userName = data.clientId;
  io.sockets.to('RoomFor:'+ userName).emit('notice', {event: data.event });
  res.writeHead(returnCode, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end();
});
```

So, a very simple server side signaling solution.

However, something in this setup is leaking badely, I have created heapdumps and tried to compare the results, but couldn't make out anything out of it.

Any thoughts?

(Btw, I went over all the threads related to node + socket.io memory leaks, none is my case... I don't use redis store, I am running with up to date node and socket.io versions.)